# How to use preprocessor-conditions to let the user type a choice with a character

Tags: c

My assignment is to use C preprocessor conditions to decide whether to perform the area of circle or square; one of the instruction emphasizes:
**when user is prompted, the user would type a number, then "R" for radius and "S" for square. I do not know if that has a meaning**.

This is my header file with my definitions declared

```
#define RADIUS 'R'
#define PI 3.14
#define CIRCLE(X) (PI*(X)*(X))
#define SIDE 'S'
#define SQ(X) ((X)*(X))
```

This is my code; I am new at this, so I am trying to see why my code doesn't take my user input choice. I will appreciate any help.

This is my code so far

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"square_circle.h"

int main(){

int number;
float area1, area2;
char choice;    


printf("Please type a whole number: ");
scanf("%d", &number);

printf("What kind of shape do you want type R or S: ");
scanf(" %c", &choice);


#if choice == RADIUS
area1 = CIRCLE(number);
printf("Your shape is a circle and your value is %f", area1);

#elif choice == SIDE
area2 = SQ(number);
printf("Your shape is a square and your value is %f", area2);

#endif  



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "preprocessor condition" - explain what you mean. If I correctly understand it (use `#if` .. `#endif` to select a part of code to execute), it's impossible.

Comment: I know but still I cannot see what the error is. All I know is "use preprocessor conditions to decide whether to perform area of square or area of a circle." All I need is help to identify my problem, so I can fix it.

Comment: I strongly suspect you misunderstood your assignment. The preprocessor and user input are as far apart as can be.

Comment: Sam: On the face of it, your assignment makes no sense.  Preprocessor conditions (like `#if`) control what happens while your program is being compiled.  But obviously it's while your program is *running* that you have to decide whether the user asked for the area of a circle or a square.

Comment: Pre-processor conditions are resolved even prior compilation of C code: [Phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases). Phase 4 - pre-processor vs. phase 7 - compiler. So, they cannot perform branching for something the user has to chose at run-time. May be, it's best to ask your teacher what the actual intention of your assignment is.

Comment: I agree with StoryTeller: It's likely that you misunderstood the assignment.  It's also possible that your instructor is confused, and gave a meaningless assignment.  In either case, I encourage you to ignore the "use C preprocessor conditions" part of the assignment, and just write a program that performs the required task.  Meanwhile you can ask your instructor for clarification n the "preprocessor conditions" constraint.

Comment: The only imaginable way: `#define RADIUS 'R'` `#define SIDE 'S'` and then in `main()`: `if (c == RADIUS)`... and `if (c == SIDE)`... or even `switch (c) { case RADIUS:` ... `case SIDE:` ... `}`.

Comment: Oh! I understand; I apologize for the trouble; English is my second language, and I know how to use if and else as code to take user input and perform the choice. The only thing that is giving me trouble is "use C preprocessor conditions to decide to perform the area of circle or square." But thanks for your clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be what your instructor had in mind, but it (more or less) meets the letter of the requirements.  It waits for the user to type `R` or `S` (more accurately, `R` or something else) and compiles some code using conditional preprocessing based on what the user typed.

#### `square_circle.h`

```
#define RADIUS 'R'
#define PI (355.0 / 113.0)
#define CIRCLE(X) (PI*(X)*(X))
#define SIDE 'S'
#define SQ(X) ((X)*(X))
```

That's a much better approximation to π than you might think — it is accurate to 7 decimal digits and only erroneous by 3 counts in the 7th decimal place — `bc -l` reports the value is `3.14159292035398230088` compared with  `3.14159265358979323844` (result of `4*a(1)`).

#### `area.c`

This code is compiled with either `-DAREA_CIRCLE` or without, and depending on that, will calculate the area of a circle or of a square when it is compiled and run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "square_circle.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s length\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    double d;
    if ((d = strtod(argv[1], 0)) == 0.0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid argument given to %s\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
#ifdef AREA_CIRCLE
    printf("Your shape is a circle with radius %g and area %g\n", d, CIRCLE(d));
#else
    printf("Your shape is a square with sides %g and area %g\n", d, SQ(d));
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

#### `chooser.c`

This is the program the user runs directly and enters the data into.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "square_circle.h"

int main(void)
{
    double number;
    char choice;    

    printf("Please type a number: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &number) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "That wasn't a number!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("What kind of shape do you want type R or S: ");
    if (scanf(" %c", &choice) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "That wasn't recognized\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char cmd[1000];
    if (choice == RADIUS)
        snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "gcc -o area area.c -DAREA_CIRCLE");
    else
        snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "gcc -o area area.c -DAREA_SQUARE");
    system(cmd);
    snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "./area %g", number);
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that using `%g` for the formats works well here; it doesn't print superfluous trailing zeros and does format both really big and really small numbers sanely too.

The code does assume you're using GCC as the compiler; you can change `gcc` to your preferred compiler name (twice).

Example runs:

```
$ ./chooser
Please type a number: 2.34
What kind of shape do you want type R or S: R
Your shape is a circle with radius 2.34 and area 17.2021
$ ./chooser
Please type a number: 2.34
What kind of shape do you want type R or S: S
Your shape is a square with sides 2.34 and area 5.4756
$ ./chooser
Please type a number: 9999 
What kind of shape do you want type R or S: R
Your shape is a circle with radius 9999 and area 3.14096e+08
$ ./chooser
Please type a number: 0.00007654
What kind of shape do you want type R or S: S
Your shape is a square with sides 7.654e-05 and area 5.85837e-09
$
```